# Notification issue

Tags: android, notifications

I have created a notification on message received here is my code:

```
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MessageBox.class);
        intent2.putExtra("action", "");   
        intent2.putExtra("action2", "");   
        PendingIntent pi= PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent2, 0);
        String body = " You have got new message!";
        String title = "New Message";
        Notification n = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,body,System.currentTimeMillis());
        n.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), title, body, pi);
        n.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
        nm.notify(10,n);
```

device moves to application when notification is displayed. But I don't want that: I want to move to my app only when I click this notification. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should

On Android training pages you can [read](http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html)

> To associate the PendingIntent created in the previous step with a
>   gesture, call the appropriate method of NotificationCompat.Builder.
>   For example, to start an activity when the user clicks the
>   notification text in the notification drawer, add the PendingIntent by
>   calling setContentIntent().

It also gives an example:

```
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent;
...
mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
```

You should review your code accordingly.